# compare 2 tags using ant task for svn

Tags: svn, ant, svnant

I am writing a build script in ant to create a .war file. I have successfully done it but now I need to compare the last tag with the newly generated tag using ant task. tagdiff is mentioned but I have not been able to find out any example on how to use it. Can you guys help me to find out difference in 2 tags generated using ant task for SVN.
I am trying something like this:

```
<svn>
<tagdiff  failonerror="true"
baseURL="${tagReposLocal}" 
destfile="${build.dir}/deploy/${buildmmdd}-${module}-d.html"
tag2="${tag.curr}" tag1="${tag.prev}"/>
</svn>
```

Answer (score 1):

The tagdiff task is documented here:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/antlibs/svn/trunk/docs/tagdiff.html?view=co

The page includes a couple of usage examples.